# Function and method debugging decorator - Part 2

Tags: python

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104178/method-and-class-method-debugging-decorator).

---

I've refactored my previous debugging decorator, and added a couple new features, and changed a few things. Here's a complete list of things that have changed:

- There is only one decorator, `Debug`, and it now supports functions, and class methods.
- Each debug message is prefixed with `[debug]` to help distinguish it from normal output.
- The output now tells you what it's outputting, rather than just outputting unreadable data.
- The decorator will now output local variables names, along with argument and keyword argument names as well.

I'm wondering the following:

- Is there a way to get the values of local variables in the function, or is that just not possible?
- Is there a shorter way to get the names of local variables than `function.__code__.co_varnames`?
- Is it a good idea to create an empty string, and then add to, and re-assign it to build an output string?
- Is this Python 3, and Python 2.7 compatible?
- How's my documentation?
- Is this code *"pythonic"*?

**debug.py**

```
from pprint import pformat
from inspect import getargspec

class Debug(object):
    """Decorator for debugging functions.

    This decorator is used to debug a function, or
    a class method. If this is applied to a normal
    function, it will print out the arguments of

    Keyword arguments:
    debug -- Whether or not you want to output debug info. Generally, a global DEBUG variable is passed in here.
    """
    def __init__(self, debug=True):
        self.debug = debug

    def __format_debug_string(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        """Return a formatted debug string.

        This is a small private helper function that will
        return a string value with certain debug information.

        Keyword arguments:
        function -- The function to debug.
        *args    -- The normal arguments of the function.
        **kwargs -- The keyword arguments of the function.
        """
        debug_string = ""
        debug_string += "[debug] {}\n".format(pformat(function))
        debug_string += "[debug] Passed args: {}\n".format(pformat(args))
        debug_string += "[debug] Passed kwargs: {}\n".format(pformat(kwargs))
        debug_string += "[debug] Locals: {}".format(pformat(function.__code__.co_varnames))
        return debug_string

    def __call__(self, function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if self.debug:
                if getargspec(function).args[0] != "self":
                    print(self.__format_debug_string(function, *args, **kwargs))
                else:
                    print(self.__format_debug_string(function, *args, **kwargs))
                    print("[debug] Parent attributes: {}".format(pformat(args[0].__dict__)))

            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
```

Here are a few small, albeit unreadable tests, but it's good enough to get the point across:

```
from debug import Debug

@Debug(debug=True)
def a(a, b):
    d = 10
    return a * b

print(a(10, 10))

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @Debug(debug=True)
    def e(self, c):
        return self.a * self.b * c

c = B(10, 10)
print(c.e(10))
```

Here's the output of these tests:

> ```
> [debug] <function a at 0x1bf9d38>
> [debug] Passed args: (10, 10)
> [debug] Passed kwargs: {}
> [debug] Locals: ('a', 'b', 'd')
> 100
> [debug] <function B.e at 0x1944ce8>
> [debug] Passed args: (<B object at 0x1bfc838>, 10)
> [debug] Passed kwargs: {}
> [debug] Locals: ('self', 'c')
> [debug] Parent attributes: {'a': 10, 'b': 10}
> 1000
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can improve the following:

> ```
>             if getargspec(function).args[0] != "self":
>                 print(self.__format_debug_string(function, *args, **kwargs))
>             else:
>                 print(self.__format_debug_string(function, *args, **kwargs))
>                 print("[debug] Parent attributes: {}".format(pformat(args[0].__dict__)))
> ```

If the code is executed no matter the statement, and it always goes first, move it above the condition: (and don't forget to reverse the condition)

```
            print(self.__format_debug_string(function, *args, **kwargs))
            if getargspec(function).args[0] == "self":
                print("[debug] Parent attributes: {}".format(pformat(args[0].__dict__)))
```

As for this:

> ```
>     debug_string = ""
>     debug_string += "[debug] {}\n".format(pformat(function))
>     debug_string += "[debug] Passed args: {}\n".format(pformat(args))
>     debug_string += "[debug] Passed kwargs: {}\n".format(pformat(kwargs))
>     debug_string += "[debug] Locals: {}".format(pformat(function.__code__.co_varnames))
>     return debug_string
> ```

You can remove the `= ""` entirely:

```
    debug_string =  "[debug] {}\n".format(pformat(function))
    debug_string += "[debug] Passed args: {}\n".format(pformat(args))
    debug_string += "[debug] Passed kwargs: {}\n".format(pformat(kwargs))
    return debug_string + "[debug] Locals: {}".format(pformat(function.__code__.co_varnames))
```

It may not look as visually stimulating, but, it's not as redundant.

> Is it a good idea to create an empty string, and then add to, and re-assign it to build an output string?

If you were directly printing these then it would be a bad idea, but in this case, not really. However, I suppose you could move them to an object, or an array and return the result of a `join` function.

You could even return it as an array, and print each `[debug]` result. Which would remove the need for the `\n`s at the end, and DRY up the `[debug]` at the beginning of the strings (*put it in the loop, not altogether*)

---

You've got a few too long lines, by PEP8 standard:

> ```
> debug -- Whether or not you want to output debug info. Generally, a global DEBUG variable is passed in here.
> debug_string += "[debug] Locals: {}".format(pformat(function.__code__.co_varnames))
> print(self.__format_debug_string(function, *args, **kwargs))
> print("[debug] Parent attributes: {}".format(pformat(args[0].__dict__)))
> ```

---

As for your documentation:

> ```
> function, it will print out the arguments of
>
> Keyword arguments:
> ```

I'm a bit confused by that, grammatically.

`__call__` is a more complex function (in my mind, at least) than `__format_debug_string`, but it has no documentation.

---

> Is this Python 3, and Python 2.7 compatible?

It ran fine when I tested it in Python 2.7.9 and 3.1.1

Comment: It doesn't have the ending underscores because it would imply that I'm overloading a "magic method".